# Running AWS commands from commandline on a ShellCommandActivity

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-data-pipeline

My original problem was that I want to increase my DynamoDB write throughput before I run the pipeline, and then decrease it when I'm done uploading (doing it max once a day, so I'm fine with the decreasing limitations).

They only way I found to do it is through a shell script that will issue the API commands to alter the throughput. How does it work with my AMI access_key and secret_key when it's a resource that pipeline creates for me? (I can't log in to set the `~/.aws/config` file and don't really want to create an AMI just for this).

Should I write the script in bash? can I use ruby/python AWS SDK packages for example? (I prefer the latter..)
How do I pass my credentials to the script? do I have runtime variables (like `@startedDate`) that I can pass as arguments to the activity with my key and secret? Do I have any other way to authenticate with either the commandline tools or the SDK package?

If there is another way to solve my original problem - please let me know. I've only got to the `ShellActivity` solution because I couldn't find anything else in documentations/forums.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. found it - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-concepts-roles.html
The `resourceRole` in the `default` object in your pipeline will be the one assigned to resources (Ec2Resource) that are created as a part of the pipeline activation.
The default one in configured to have all your permissions and AWS commandline and SDK packages are automatically looking for those credentials so no need to update ~/.aws/config of pass credentials manually.